# Getting current Parse Cloud code release version programatically

Tags: parse-platform

Whenever you deploy to cloud code, Parse.com outputs the new release version.

**"New release is named v296 (using Parse JavaScript SDK v1.4.2)"**

Is there anyway to get this information programatically within cloud code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a way to do that without a small trick:

I capture the console everytime I deploy a new version and then I parse the last line to get the version number. With that information, I update a collection in my Parse environment with this version code.

Whenever I need this information in cloud code (or even in the client), I query this collection to get it.

That's not the best way to do it, but it works...

Note: if, for some reason, you could not capture the console after deploy, you can also use "parse logs" and search for a string like "Deployed v296 with triggers:" and do the same after parsing it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @oscar-eduardo I was thinking along similar lines but i prefer your solution - Parse should really make this info available in the environment.